# UITableViewCell imageView padding

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to set up margins or paddings for UITableView cells imageView, how could I do that?
With `heightForRowAtIndexPath` I can only set rows height. And it just enlarges the image in cell if I increase it.

Here is my cellForRow method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kSystemFontSize];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Currently I only know one method how I could do it - shrink the image content of the images using photoshop or similiar program while staying at the same time. But such method would take a lot of time, and I guess there should be easier way to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without subclassing:

```
cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, .5, .5);
```

change the '.5' with the right proportion for your case

Comment: That's a smart idea! By the way, the right hand side expression can be further simplified to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)`.

Comment: Hi I'm from the future, It's not working :)

Answer (score 9):

The best solution here is to create your own cell, add image, labels inside of `contentView` and tweak them how you want.

But there's also another way, again you need to create a subclass from `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews` selector:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this seems to result in my text being covered by the image.

Answer (score 3):

This works on iOS 7:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect imageViewFrame = self.imageView.frame;
    imageViewFrame.origin.x = 10;
    imageViewFrame.origin.y += 5;
    imageViewFrame.size.height -= 10;
    imageViewFrame.size.width -= 10;
    self.imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
}
```

Comment: that seems to be very creative, but unfortunately it's not working for me. Any idea?

Comment: @umair151 it works for me, although I'm using `.offsetInPlace(dx:dy:)` rather than manipulating the `.origin` and `.size` properties directly

Comment: For those wondering, `offsetInPlace` is the equivalent of `CGRectOffset`.

Answer (score 1):

updated for swift3

```
cell?.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
```