# iOS 7 UITableviewCell setIndentationLevel did not apply for imageView

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am using this code `[cell setIndentationLevel:7];` with normal `UITableViewCell` but it display too difference between iOS 6 and iOS 7.

**iOS 6 and ealier**
[image]

**iOS 7**

[image]

How can i fix iOS 7's error?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar questions [UITableViewCell imageView padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924412/uitableviewcell-imageview-padding) and [ios7 uitableviewcell image left offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080039/ios7-uitableviewcell-image-left-offset) offer solution over subclassing. In iOS7 UIImageView sticks to left edge and you need to reposition it manually.

In your case position is based on indentation level:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.indentationLevel*self.indentationWidth;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;
}
```